# Javascript not working for first time in my HTML File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have checked and tried various solutions provided here previously but still my javascript is not working for the first time. If I refresh the page manually only once, my javascript gets active in a very fine manner.

After refreshing the page, I am very fine with javascript but if I put this same script in other new HTML file then same issue found on loading the page first time.

My script actually search for a text in the HTML file and change the text style every where it is found in that page.

Following is the script that I have used::

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    function Hilitor(id, tag){
      var targetNode = document.getElementById(id) || document.body;
      var hiliteTag = tag || "EM";
      var skipTags = new RegExp("^(?:" + hiliteTag + "|SCRIPT|FORM|SPAN)$");
      var colors = ["#ff6", "#a0ffff", "#9f9", "#f99", "#f6f"];
      var wordColor = [];
      var colorIdx = 0;
      var matchRegex = "";
      var openLeft = false;
      var openRight = false;
      // characters to strip from start and end of the input string
      var endCharRegex = new RegExp("^[^\\\w]+|[^\\\w]+$", "g");
      // characters used to break up the input string into words
      var breakCharRegex = new RegExp("[^\\\w'-]+", "g");
      this.setMatchType = function(type){
        switch(type) {
          case "left":
            this.openLeft = false;
            this.openRight = true;
            break;
          case "right":
            this.openLeft = true;
            this.openRight = false;
            break;
          case "open":
            this.openLeft = this.openRight = true;
            break;
          default:
            this.openLeft = this.openRight = false;
         }
      };

      this.setRegex = function(input){
        input = input.replace(endCharRegex, "");
        input = input.replace(breakCharRegex, "|");
        input = input.replace(/^\||\|$/g, "");
        if(input) {
          var re = "(" + input + ")";
          if(!this.openLeft) re = "\\b" + re;
          if(!this.openRight) re = re + "\\b";
          matchRegex = new RegExp(re, "i");
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      };

      this.getRegex = function(){
        var retval = matchRegex.toString();
        retval = retval.replace(/(^\/(\\b)?|\(|\)|(\\b)?\/i$)/g, "");
        retval = retval.replace(/\|/g, " ");
        return retval;
      };

      // recursively apply word highlighting
      this.hiliteWords = function(node){ 
        if(node === undefined || !node) return;
        if(!matchRegex) return;
        if(skipTags.test(node.nodeName)) return;
        if(node.hasChildNodes()) {
          for(var i=0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++)
            this.hiliteWords(node.childNodes[i]);
        }
        if(node.nodeType == 3) { // NODE_TEXT
          if((nv = node.nodeValue) && (regs = matchRegex.exec(nv))) {
            if(!wordColor[regs[0].toLowerCase()]) {
              wordColor[regs[0].toLowerCase()] = colors[colorIdx++ % colors.length];
            }
            var match = document.createElement(hiliteTag);
            match.appendChild(document.createTextNode(regs[0]));
            match.style.backgroundColor = wordColor[regs[0].toLowerCase()];
            match.style.fontStyle = "inherit";
            match.style.fontWeight = "900";
            match.style.color = "#000";
            var after = node.splitText(regs.index);
            after.nodeValue = after.nodeValue.substring(regs[0].length);
            node.parentNode.insertBefore(match, after);
          }
        };
      };

      // remove highlighting
      this.remove = function(){
        var arr = document.getElementsByTagName(hiliteTag);
        while(arr.length && (el = arr[0])) {
          var parent = el.parentNode;
          parent.replaceChild(el.firstChild, el);
          parent.normalize();
        }
      };

      // start highlighting at target node
      this.apply = function(input){
        this.remove();
        if(input === undefined || !input) return;
        if(this.setRegex(input)) {
          this.hiliteWords(targetNode);
        }
      };

    }

    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) {
          url = window.location.href;
        }
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    var query = getParameterByName('query');
    var myHilitor = new Hilitor("spnId");
    myHilitor.apply(query);
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide the script

Comment: I have added my script but don't know why is it not displayed here

Comment: Now you can Check my code. Please help me If there is any solution for it.